# How To Move Div Elements A Little To The Left

Tags: html, css, blogger

I would like to move #wctopdropcont elements slightly to the left. I have tried applying values for margin and padding however it simply doesn't work. I would ideally want the text to be 20px to the left. The URL to my blog is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com and below I have included the entire hovering navigation bar's html and css coding.

```
#wctopdropcont{ /* width of the main bar categories */
width:100%;
height:45px;
display:block;
padding: 5.5px 0 0 0;
z-index:100;
top:0px;
left: 0px;
position:fixed;

background:#f8f8f8;
  }

#wctopdropnav{ /* social */
float: right;
width:97%;
height:7px;
display:block;
padding:0px;
}
#wctopdropnav ul{
float:right;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
#wctopdropnav li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
line-height:13px;
margin-left: 4px;
padding: 10px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px;/* height of the clicked bar */
background:#f8f8f8;
}
#wctopdropnav li a, #wctopdropnav li a:link{
color:#000000;
float: right;
display:block;
margin-left: 4px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 9.5px!important;
font-family: karla, arial!important;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight: normal!important;
letter-spacing : 0.09em;
}

#wctopdropnav li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li a:active,    #wctopdropnav .current_page_item a  {
color:black;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 5px;
background: #f8f8f8; /* Old browsers */
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
filter:black;  
}
#wctopdropnav li li a, #wctopdropnav li li a:link, #wctopdropnav li li a:visited{
font-size: 9.5px;
background:#f8f8f8;
color: #000000;
width: 90px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
line-height: 15px;
position: relative;
}

#wctopdropnav li li a:hover, #wctopdropnav li li a:active {
color: black;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8; 
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
background: #f8f8f8;
filter: #f8f8f8;
}
#wctopdropnav li ul{
z-index:9999;
position:absolute;
left:-999em;
height:auto;
width:170px;
margin:22px 0 0 0;
padding: 8px 0 0 0;
}

 #wctopdropnav li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li li li:hover ul, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover ul, #topwctopdropnav li li.sfhover ul, #topwctopdropnav li li li.sfhover ul{
left:auto
}

#wctopdropnav li:hover, #wctopdropnav li.sfhover{
position:static
}  
</style>
<div id='wctopdropcont'>
 <div id='wctopdropnav'>
<ul>

<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/about-blankesque-blog.html'>About</a></li>


 <li><a href='#'>Categories</a>

         <ul>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Beauty'>Beauty</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Blogging'>Blogging</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Fashion'>Fashion</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Fragrance'>Fragrance</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Haul'>Haul</a></li>
              <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Lifestyle'>Lifestyle</a></li>
           <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/search/label/Skin &amp; Hair'>Skin &amp; Hair</a></li>
       </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/contact-blankesque-for-press.html'>Contact</a></li>

   <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/discalimer-policy_13.html'>Policies</a></li>
   </ul>

    </div></div>
```

Comment: Your link is not working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `#wctopdropnav ul` selector, you have `margin: 0` so if you want to override that and add `margin-right: 20px;` then it must be declared after it like so.

```
#wctopdropnav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#wctopdropnav ul {
    ...
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9ru7z46f/)**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move the nav text left by applying right margin to `#wctopdropnav`.

```
#wctopdropnav {
  float: right;
  width: 97%;
  height: 7px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```